# Tkinter Label, TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects

Tags: python, tkinter, concatenation, typeerror

I am coding a dice simulator that will roll either a 6 sided dice or an 8 sided dice. I am using Python 2.7 and Tkinter. Here is my file with a dictionary with the dice in:

```
DICE = dict(
    sixsided={'name': 'Six Sided Dice',
              'side': 6},
    eightsided = {'name': 'Eight Sided Dice',
                  'side': 8}
    )
names = ['Six Sided Dice', 'Eight Sided Dice']
```

And here is the code from my main file that is causing my problem:

```
diceroll = random.randrange(1,DICE[selecteddice]["side"])
Label(diceroll, text="You rolled a " + diceroll + " on the " + DICE[selecteddice]["name"])
```

My problem is the error message that occurs when I run my file:

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects

Any help is greatly appreciated!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you were expecting something like this:

[image: Example window]

You have to pass the `Tk()` class *assuming it was imported as `from Tkinter import *`* as the first argument to a Tk widget:

```
root = Tk()
Label(root, text="You rolled a " + diceroll + " on the " + DICE[selecteddice]["name"])
```

But now you'll end up with `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects` so use the `str()` method to convert `diceroll` to a string

```
Label(root, text="You rolled a " + str(diceroll) + " on the " + DICE[selecteddice]["name"])
```

**`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'instance' objects`
error occurs because data cannot be retrieved as strings or int's from a class without using `__repr__` , `__str__` methods** *but rather as objects*

since you haven't displayed your full code this is far as I can help

```
#The top image was produced thanks to this
import random
from Tkinter import *

selecteddice = 'sixsided'

DICE = dict(
    sixsided={'name': 'Six Sided Dice',
              'side': 6},
    eightsided = {'name': 'Eight Sided Dice',
                  'side': 8}
    )
names = ['Six Sided Dice', 'Eight Sided Dice']

root = Tk()

diceroll = random.randrange(1,DICE[selecteddice]["side"])
Label(root, text="You rolled a " + str(diceroll) + " on the " + DICE[selecteddice]["name"]).pack()

root.mainloop()
```